# Defining __getattr__ and __getitem__ on a function has no effect

Tags: python, metaprogramming

*Disclaimer* This is just an exercise in meta-programming, it has no practical
purpose.

I've assigned `__getitem__` and `__getattr__` methods on a function object, but
there is no effect...

```
def foo():
  print "foo!"

foo.__getitem__ = lambda name: name
foo.__getattr__ = lambda name: name
foo.baz = 'baz'
```

Sanity check that we *can* assign properties to a function:

```
>>> foo.baz
'baz'
```

Neat.  How about the "magic getters"?

```
>>> foo.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar'

>>> foo['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

>>> getattr(foo, 'bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Is it possible to have a "magic getter" on a function object?

Answer (score 7):

Nope!  Assigning `__getitem__` to an instance doesn't work on *any* type of object:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__getattr__ = lambda name: name
>>> a.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

**And** you can't define `__getattr__` on the built-in function type:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType.__getitem__ = lambda name: name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'
```

***And*** you can't subclass `types.FunctionType`:

```
>>> import types
>>> class F(types.FunctionType):
...   pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
type 'function' is not an acceptable base type
```

Comment: @kindall points this out below, but I'll mention it here so it stays with the answer.  new-style classes do not use the "normal" method resolution with `__getattr__` and its friends.  `a.foo` is translated internally to `type(a).__getattr__('foo')`.  So the property `__getattr__` that is stored in `a.__dict__` is not found.  Hope that makes sense... :-/

Answer (score 3):

At least on new-style classes (which are the only kind in Python 3 and the kind you should be using in Python 2), Python only looks for magic methods on the class (and its ancestors), never on the instance. [Docs here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes).

And of course you can't modify the function type, or derive from it. As you've found, however, any class with a `__call__()` method makes callable instances, so that's the way to do it.

Comment: All true - I wanted to share a little bit more of the full story so that anyone who stumbled here would not have to go poking around the docs to find this stuff out.  but yeah, new-style classes call `type(obj).__getattr__`.  Which is documented, sure, but counterintuitive to me... why not just use the normal method resolution?

Comment: "The rationale behind this behaviour lies with a number of special methods such as `__hash__()` and `__repr__()` that are implemented by all objects, including type objects. If the implicit lookup of these methods used the conventional lookup process, they would fail when invoked on the type object itself."

Comment: I'm reading through the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) multiple times and I don't see where it explicitly says "Python never looks for magic methods on the instance", and I don't even see that it clearly explicitly says "...only looks on the class (and its ancestors)". Can you cite the exact URL/section? Also, is that worth a docbug?

Answer (score 2):

AHHA!  Use `__call__`, and wrap the function in `F()`

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.__dict__['fn'] = fn

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return name

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return name

>>> foo = F(foo)
>>> f.bar
'bar'
>>> f['foo']
'foo'
>>> foo()
foo!
```

Comment: Basically your describing decorators :)

Comment: Yup, and I played with this as a decorator, but interesting things break down... if I decorate a method with a class, when calling the method it does not become a bound method.  so a "class-as-decorator" does not appear to be the "same thing" as a "function-as-decorator".  We'll see, I'll post my findings here.

Comment: They are both identical in what they provide, they both return a `callable` object. Its just that class like decorators are neater and cleaner

Comment: If you are decorating a plain function, yes, but they are not identical when decorating a class or instance method.  The function returned by the function-as-decorator gets bound to the instance, but the class-as-decorator does not.  *Unless* you use `__get__`, not `__call__`.  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2837193) to see what I mean.  All `function` types have a `__get__` function that binds them to a receiver, but the class-callable does not.

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Comment: @colinta: I can't follow these comments clearly, can you please add all that to your answer? Bottom line: is coding like this a good idea or not?

Comment: It's a terrible idea to code like this! but that doesn't mean you shouldn't know that it can be done and how.