# Same name regular and property functions under the same class in python

Tags: python-2.7

I was wondering, is it possible to have one property function and one regular function with the same name under the same class in python? I want to do something like this:

```
class foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = []

  @property
  def get_x(self):
    return self.x

  def get_x(self, n):
    return self.x[n]
```

So I would be able to call it with the next different ways:

```
f = foo()

# get the whole list
x = f.get_x

# One way to get the n-th element
x = f.get_x[n]

# Another way to get the n-th element
x = f.get_x(n)
```

I know it's essentially the same thing, and since I can live with just the property function it's not a big deal. I just want to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803384/defining-getattr-and-getitem-on-a-function-has-no-effect), you can't add `__getitem__` on a function.

Additionally, you can't add a method `__call__` to a regular `list`.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.__call__ = lambda n: a(n)
a(1) # AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__call__'
```

With this in mind, you might have to make your own `list` data structure and add custom behavior for when it's called.

```
class callableList(list):
    def __call__(self, index):
        return self[index]

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = callableList()

    @property
    def get_x(self):
        return self.x
```

The resulting attribute `x` can be both subscripted and called.

```
f = foo()
f.x.extend([1,2,3])

print f.get_x[0] # 1
print f.get_x(1) # 2
print f.x(2)     # 3
```