# Set property on a function object

Tags: python, function, properties, getattr, python-descriptors

Is it possible to assign property on a function object the similar way we assign it on class instances. My desired behaviour is like this

```py
def prop():
    print("I am a property")

def my_func():
    print("Just a function call")


my_func.prop = prop
my_func.prop  # prints 'I am a property'
```

I am able to invoke it as a function call `my_func.prop()`, but is there a way to override `__getattribute__` or something to achieve this result?

I have tried attaching it on a class

```py
setattr(my_func.__class__, "prop", property(prop))
```

but definitely that's not the way

```
TypeError: cannot set 'prop' attribute of immutable type 'function'
```

Comment: You can set attributes on a function, but I'm not sure why you would want to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function attributes - uses and abuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses)

Comment: @roganjosh nope, this one covers the right topic slightly more https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803385/19838445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Limitations

So basically Python does not allow to do the described thing as

a) it is not possible to create your own "function" class `Base class "FunctionType" is marked final and cannot be subclassed`

```py
import types
class F(types.FunctionType):
    pass
```

or

```py
base = type(lambda: ...)

class F(base):
    pass
```

because `TypeError: type 'function' is not an acceptable base type`

b) it is not possible to modify existing built-in `function` type

```
TypeError: cannot set 'prop' attribute of immutable type 'function'
```

#### Possible solution

Create your own `Callable` class which would be a wrapper around your function

```py
import typing
class MyFunc:
    def __init__(self, func: typing.Callable):
        self.f = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then assign property as you would on any other class

```py
def prop(self):
    print(f"I am a property of {self}")

@MyFunc
def my_func():
    print("Just a function call")

setattr(my_func.__class__, "prop", property(prop))
my_func.prop
```

Example above is just for my question with dynamic assignment, you probably would you just `@property` decorator on a method within class definition.